# CORS issue with remote images in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, cors

I'm new with Vue.js and currently facing a CORS issue when trying to use a remote address for img src. I googled the problem and saw that adding the following:

Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = true;
Vue.http.headers.common['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = "*";

can solve the issue (which makes sense), but so far I have no idea where I'm supposed to add it. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The remote host would need to set those headers in their server to allow you CORS access, you can't grant yourself access to someone else's server.  But  as far as I know CORS shouldn't come into play if all you're doing is an `<img>` tag with a remote `src`; can you clarify what you're doing that's triggering this?

Answer (score 0):

The image host must allow your domain. You cannot set that in your code or host as you have mentioned. The image host needs to set `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` and this can be achieved by using `.htaccess` file.